# Glfw getting the alphabits, depthbits and stencilbits

Tags: opengl, glfw

Looking at the manual for GLFW you can use `glfwGetVideoModes( GLFWvidmode *modes, int maxcount )` to go the display modes. However this only gives you.

```
int Width, Height; // Video resolution
int RedBits; // Number of red bits
int GreenBits; // Number of green bits
int BlueBits; // Number of blue bits
```

To open a window you need a few more params, what is the best way to get the remaining ones?

(apart from mode)
glfwOpenWindow(int width, int height, int redbits, int greenbits, int bluebits,
               **int alphabits, int depthbits, int stencilbits**, int mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the values you need and hope for the best.  Perhaps provide a fallback if you can't get what you want.

Generally:

1. `alphabits <= 8` should generally work.
2. `depthbits <= 16` should generally work, `24` or `32` may also work.
3. `stencilbits <= 8` might work.

You may also find [2.16 in the FAQ](http://www.glfw.org/faq.html#2_16) informative.

Comment: The manual says that the function does the best it can. "all parameters except the window mode are matched as closely as possible to what is available on the system". Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

The de facto standard for graphics cards today is to support 24 depth bits and 8 stencil bits. 32 depth bits is very rare.

What you probably want to do is to request 8 alpha bits, 24 depth bits, and 8 stencil bits. If you don't need stencil or alpha, request 0 bits for them (this way you don't need to worry about the stencil operation state for instance).